# OS fails to boot after installing discrete graphics card

Tags: boot, graphics-card

I have [a machine with an Intel H67 chipset and a single PCI-E x16 slot](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883113203) that works fine displaying from the onboard video card.  I purchased [an MSI N730K-1GD5LP/OC GeForce GT 730 video card](http://us.msi.com/product/vga/N730K-1GD5LPOC.html#hero-specification) to improve performance and installed it. I connected a monitor to the new graphics card via an HDMI cable and booted the machine up.

The POST screen came up, the LEDs on the keyboard lit up, the motherboard fans and graphics card fans all spun up.  However, after a few seconds, the keyboard become unresponsive, the motherboard beeped twice, and after a minute, the machine rebooted on its own, repeating the process.  The bootloader menu never displayed.

Attempting to hit the 'Delete' button to enter the BIOS does not work while the new graphics card is installed.

Uninstalling the graphics card and reconnecting the onboard video card restores operation to normal, allowing me to boot into the OS as normal.

Suspecting that this may have been a result of not having enough power with the original 300W power supply, I installed a 650W power supply, but found the same behavior.

Do I have a busted graphics card?  A bad PCI-E slot?  How do I troubleshoot further from here?

Comment: How exactly does one reconnect on onboard graphics card if its built into the hardware?

Comment: By attaching a VGA cable to it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a faulty display adapter to me as well, which is not uncommon.

According to [Intel's list](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-010249.htm), two POST beeps = "Video error (no add-in graphics card installed)".  Which, to me, confirms the display adapter is faulty.

To troubleshoot if it's the display adapter or the machine, try with another (known-good) adapter in its place. Also, try the suspect graphic adapter in another computer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [beep codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm), the beep is caused by a faulty circuit.
To troubleshoot the problem, there are some things you can do. Try a different pci slot (if possible) and if the problem persists, try to get another graphics card (with lower specs recommended) and try again if the problem happens again. Before doing anything, I would search if that graphics card is compatible with your motherboard, chipset and cpu. If according to the specifications everything is as it should, then go on and try another pci slot, and after that (if still the same), another gpu as I told you before.

Comment: This motherboard only has one PCE-I x16 slot.

Comment: Then try to test that graphics card on another pc, or test your computer's pci with another card. As for the card you have, it supports PCE-I x16.